# Saving selected option onChange - HTML / Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, onchange

I haven't done this in quite a few years and forgot. Had to look up the onchange and cookie use too..
Anyways, I want the cookie to save the selected value during the onChange.  I know there are better ways to do this i.e. with POST, but I cannot alter the rest of the page and code.

```
<table style="background-color: #FFDD18;" width="100%" class="yearSelect"><tr>
<td><b>Select Year: </b>

<select name="yearEffSelect" id="yearEffSelect"
   onchange="setCookie('YearEffSelected',__WHAT_GOES_HERE?__,1)">
<option value='2001'>2001</option>
<option value='2002'>2002</option>
<option value='2003'>2003</option>
<option value='2004'>2004</option>
<option value='2005'>2005</option>
<option value='2006'>2006</option>
<option value='2007'>2007</option>
<option value='2008'>2008</option>
<option value='2009'>2009</option>
<option value='2010'>2010</option>
<option value='2011' selected>2011</option>

</select>
</td>
</tr></table>
```

So, question: What code goes in "**__WHAT_GOES_HERE?__**" ?

Something along the lines of  document.getId('yearEffSelected').getValue() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
this.value
```

to get the selected value.

This is assuming you have a function named `setCookie` that already exists.